# swapon fails on boot, Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: swap, systemd

I have the following in my /etc/fstab, and /dev/sdb1 is correctly formatted as a swap space. `swapon -a` works without problems.

```
/dev/sdb1 none swap sw 0 0
```

However, every time I reboot the system, swapping is off. /var/log/syslog contains the following:

```
Sep  5 09:17:59 puffin systemd[1]: Activating swap /dev/sdb1...
Sep  5 09:17:59 puffin swapon[757]: /sbin/swapon: invalid option -- 'o'
Sep  5 09:17:59 puffin swapon[757]: Usage:
Sep  5 09:17:59 puffin swapon[757]:  swapon -a [-e] [-v] [-f]             enable all swaps from /etc/fstab
Sep  5 09:17:59 puffin swapon[757]:  swapon [-p priority] [-v] [-f] <special>  enable given swap
Sep  5 09:17:59 puffin swapon[757]:  swapon -s                            display swap usage summary
Sep  5 09:17:59 puffin swapon[757]:  swapon -h                            display help
Sep  5 09:17:59 puffin swapon[757]:  swapon -V                            display version
Sep  5 09:17:59 puffin swapon[757]: The <special> parameter:
Sep  5 09:17:59 puffin swapon[757]:  {-L label | LABEL=label}             LABEL of device to be used
Sep  5 09:17:59 puffin swapon[757]:  {-U uuid  | UUID=uuid}               UUID of device to be used
Sep  5 09:17:59 puffin swapon[757]:  <device>                             name of device to be used
Sep  5 09:17:59 puffin swapon[757]:  <file>                               name of file to be used
Sep  5 09:17:59 puffin systemd[1]: dev-sdb1.swap: Swap process exited, code=exited status=1
```

It seems that `systemd` is calling `swapon` with the `-o` option, which `swapon` does not recognize. I noticed that there exist some other versions of `swapon` that do support an `-o` option, for example here:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/swapon.8.html. However, the version of `swapon` that comes with Ubuntu 17.04 does not have an `-o` option.

Question: how can I fix this? In particular, where is `systemd` configured to use the `swapon -o` command? I cannot find the corresponding unit file; there are no files under /etc/systemd ending in `.swap` or containing the word `swap`.

Additional information: the command `systemctl start dev-sdb1.swap` also does not work. It fails, and `journalctl -xe` shows an error similar to the above.

Most answers to similar questions are for people who forgot to format their swap partitions. Note that this is a different problem. Thanks!

Comment: It may be unrelated, as the syslog output is interesting, but 17.04 comes with a swapfile instead of a swap partition by default if you install it fresh rather than upgrading from it. What's the output of `swapon --show`?

Comment: I installed 17.04 by upgrading from an earlier version, so no swap file for me. The output of `swapon --show` is `swapon: unrecognized option '--show'`. The output of `swapon -s` is `Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority` `/dev/sdb1                               partition       16777212        0       -1`.

Comment: ok, clear... but another strange thing... your version of `swapon` doesn't recognise `--show` either... what about `swapon --version`?

Comment: You probably have two problems. 1) sdb is probably a USB drive, correct? It may not be ready/mounted at the time it tries to open the swap partition, and 2) you should try using the UUID (`UUID=`)of the swap partition (`sudo blkid`) instead of /dev/sdb1. I'm not sure, but I think there is a parameter that you can place in fstab that will make it wait for the drive... but I don't know what it is... homework for you...

Comment: ps: `swapon -V` should show version 2.29 for 17.04